# USB umount stats: inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: debian, mount, usb-drive

I'm writing some code for my program to mount a flash drive using

```
mount("/dev/sda", "/media", "vfat", MS_NOATIME, NULL)
```

and unmount using

```
status = umount2("/media",MNT_DETACH);
qDebug("USB unmount - status = %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

The message says: `USB unmount - status = Inappropriate ioctl for device`
when in fact the flash was successfully unmounted. Am I doing anything wrong here?

The target system is debian and I'm using C++ with Qt

Comment: What is the value of `status`?

Comment: Which language is this? Python?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The status has a value of 0. According to http://linux.die.net/man/2/umount, it should be successful?

Comment: Yes, a return value of 0 means it was successful. I've added a more complete answer that tries to explain what you saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing - a zero return from a system call interface function, indicating success, but a nonzero `errno` - is normal. This is because, in general, system call interface functions, and a few other C functions, only set `errno` when there's a failure, and otherwise leave it unchanged. (Strictly speaking, the value of `errno` after a successful function call is *unspecified*.)

Here's a quote from the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html):

> The value of errno shall be defined only after a call to a function for which it is explicitly stated to be set and until it is changed by the next function call or if the application assigns it a value.
>
> The value of errno should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value.
>
> The setting of errno after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that errno shall not be modified.

Looking at the documentation for [umount2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umount):

> On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

So your call to `umount2` succeeded, and the value of `errno` is unspecified. It is likely that `errno` was set by some other recently-called function that failed. You can run `strace` on your program to see which system call failed; since the error was `ioctl`-related, the function was probably part of the stdio infrastructure probing the attributes of stdout, and it's normal for that to happen.

Comment: good call. I should check the returned value first and then printout error messages. The errno was indeed set by previous function calls.